# Android Receiveing data from another apps with limited files

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I am following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html#handling-content) example to receiving data from another application on share action. Now I have successfully handle the data with single file and multiple files and used in application.

But I want to set limit for multiple file received. I have set the limit inside my application it'll opening first and then finish instead of this I want don't allow to open my application like WhatsApp have done like if you passing more than 10 files app was not open instead its just display message like "**Cannot share more than 10 media files**".

Any suggestion will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You could receive the intent in a separate broadcast receiver. This receiver will check the file and decide if the app should be open. If ok, you launch your activity with the appropriate intent, if there is too many files, you just display a toast or a dialog and don't launch the activity

Comment: "it'll opening first and then finish". So don't finish it. Just show the message `Toast.make(context, "Canno share more than 10").show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution by myself as we open the default application activity instead of open transparent activity and check whether the image list getting more than 10 or not if more than 10 display Toast message and return otherwise use in application.

Now I have also face the strange issue that when you getting images from Google Photo Application we'll be getting URI now if you forword that URI to another activity it'll be not available to another. Just because Google Photo App have allow accessing for single activity only. If you forword that using `intent.putextra` and pass to another activity and access that image you'll be getting error **"Permission denied to access"**.

So the solution is just find the absolute path and store image in your application and then forword to another component of your application.

To find the absolute path [code is here](http://pratiknandha.blogspot.in/2015/08/get-absolute-path-for-all-support.html)

[Receiving Simple Data from Other Apps](http://pratiknandha.blogspot.in/2015/08/receiving-simple-data-from-other-apps.html)

Hope this will helpful to you